# windows 8 update folders not hidden

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-update

some strange folders are being create in c:.
Each of these folders contains an "amd64" folder.

These supposed to be windows update stuff, but are created visible.

What could be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running a 64bit OS. The reason for that folder would be application drivers that was most likely updated. Normally a backup copy is created first, and this is where the AMD64 bit folder comes in. So to put it in a nutshell, it is needed should your system experiencing corresponding driver issues, it can restore or 'roll back' to the backup drivers.

Comment: Ok, but normally these folders are "invisible". I my case, they are always visible.

Comment: Have you tried to hide them in the properties pane?